# Scraping text from webite using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I've managed to get to a stage where i can open up this website https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle

Enter a vehicle registration number, click continue, click yes this is the right vehicle and continue again to the next page.

Now looking for how I can pull the Fuel type data from this website i.e. the car listed below (my parents car) will be PETROL. Can't seem to figure it out - done a lot of googling!

I'll also want to pull the cylinder capacity (CC): entry and Year of Manufacture.

```
def vehicleRegChecker():

    from selenium import webdriver
    import time

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get("https://vehicleenquiry.service.gov.uk/ConfirmVehicle")
    driver.find_element_by_name("Vrm").send_keys("VX02LTE")

    python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@name='Continue'][@type='submit']")[0]
    python_button.click()

    python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@data-val='true'][@type='radio']")[0]
    python_button.click()

    python_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@name='Continue'][@type='submit']")[0]
    python_button.click()

vehicleRegChecker()
```

Comment: What element contains the fuel type?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is what you're looking for:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('list-summary-item')

print(elems[2].text)
print(elems[3].text)
```

and because it has the title too if you want only the values do this:

```
elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('list-summary-item')

print(elems[2].text.split('\n')[1])
print(elems[3].text.split('\n')[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

after all your code run this:

```py
fuel_type = driver.find_element_by_id('FuelTypeShown').text
years_of_manufacture = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//li[.//*[contains(text(), "Year of manufacture")]]//strong').text
cc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="CylinderCapacity"]//strong').text
print(fuel_type)
print(years_of_manufacture)
print(cc)
>>> PETROL
>>> 2002
>>> 1390 cc
```